# Django. PostgreSQL. regexp_split_to_table not working

Tags: regex, django, postgresql, escaping

I am trying to tokenize my table fields with a query.

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table(mytable.field_name, E'\\s+') from mytable limit 20;
```

This works when I execute it from psql shell but when I do:

```
from django.db import connection cursor=connection.cursor() 
cursor.execute("SELECT regexp_split_to_table(mytable.field_name,E'\\s+')
                FROM mytable LIMIT 20") 
cursor.fetchall()
```

... it fails to return tokens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it seems psycopg doent execute postgres functions.

Comment: Don't know much about Django, but here's an idea: "SELECT * FROM (SELECT regexp_split_to_table(fld, E'\\s+') FROM tbl LIMIT 20) x LIMIT 20". In case Django doesn't understand that a function can return a set of values.

Comment: that does not work either. say one on fields is "SOPA blackout", it wont return [("SOPA","blackout")] but will return [("SOPA blackout")]

Comment: So the query **does** return something? Try `' +')` instead of `E'\\s+')` to determine if the escape string is the problem. May be that you have to double the \ to arrive at `E'\\\\s+')`. Just hat a similar problem here in the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash is treated as meta-character by Django and is interpreted inside double quotes.
So one layer of `E'\\s+')` gets stripped before the string arrives at the PostgreSQL server, which will see `E'\s+')`. The escape string will result in `'s+'` which in turn will make `regexp_split_to_table()` split your strings at any number of `s` instead of non-printing space, which the character class shorthand `\s` stands for in regular expressions.

Double your backslashes in the string to get what you intended: `E'\\\\s+')`:

```
"SELECT regexp_split_to_table(field_name, E'\\\\s+') FROM mytable LIMIT 20"
```

As an alternative, to avoid problems with the special meaning of the backslash `\`, you can use `[[:space:]]` to denote the same character class:

```
"SELECT regexp_split_to_table(field_name, '[[:space:]]+') FROM mytable LIMIT 20"
```

Details in the chapter ["Pattern Matching" in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CHARACTER-ENTRY-ESCAPES-TABLE).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to new in Django `F`, `Func`, and supprot for postgresql `ArrayField` you can now call this function like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value, TextField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db.models.expressions import Func

MyTable.objects.annotate(
  some_field_splitted=Func(
      F('some_field'), 
      Value(","), 
      function='regexp_split_to_array',
      output_field=ArrayField(TextField())
   )
).filter(some_field_splitted__contains=[HERE_SOME_VALUE])
```