# SQL select where column begins with \

Tags: sql, pattern-matching

I'm trying to find all the data in `ColumnX` where the Data begins with a `\`.
Is `like '\%'` what I'm looking for? But the `\` has to be at the beginning.

Comment: Does this not work for you `where col like '\%'` ?

Comment: That should work. If you are querying from a language like java or C# where '\' has special meaning, you may need to escape your query string ('\\%' or @"\%") first

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The backslash `\` can have special meaning in `LIKE` patterns. It's the default `ESCAPE` character in [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) or [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) - but not in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm) or [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). (Can be modified with an added `ESCAPE` clause in subtly varying ways, follow link for your RDBMS.)

In addition to that, **PostgreSQL** used to interpret POSIX-style escapes in strings (a.k.a. "C escape syntax") before version 9.1 and [**MySQL** still does in version 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html)). There you have to double `\` to `\\` to get an ordinary backslash.

According to standard SQL, `\` is *not* a meta character in strings. PostgreSQL eventually switched to standard behavior and introduced a special escape-string-syntax with `E''` and the config settings [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) and [`escape_string_warning`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-ESCAPE-STRING-WARNING) to still allow escaped string when needed.

Since **Postgres 9.1** `standard_conforming_strings = on` by default. So you write:

```
... col LIKE '\\%'    -- double once to get 1 literal backslash in LIKE pattern
```

Else you have to write:

```
... col LIKE E'\\\\%'  -- double twice to also disable special meaning as escape char
```

---

On top of that, `\` also has special meaning in many **client programs and programming languages**. If strings get interpreted before they even reach the database engine, you may have to double the `\` another time (or escape it in some other fashion). See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8907041/939860), for instance.

Comment: And in MySQL the backslash has particular significance in `LIKE` patterns as an escape character.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed  '\%' is what you need. The following statement brings all the data where columnX starts with '\'.

```
select * from table_name where columnX like '\%'
```

Comment: Maby you have to escape the "\", depending on the database or programming language.

Comment: I don't think that '\' character needs to be escaped in SQL statements. I have tried for MySQL and Oracle and it worked.

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk - [Shouldn't have worked in MySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) `\%`  Matches one `%` character as `\\` is the pattern escape character.

Comment: If you run it directly on the database it should work with the most, but when you run it out of a language like java or ruby you have to escape these special characters. In java it would be "\\%" and ruby should be sth. like "\\%%"

Comment: I've ran it directly on the db, escaping would probably be required otherwise if running through a programming language as @tbraun89 mentioned.

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk - `\%` is documented to match a percent not a back slash in MySQL see my earlier link.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

`select * from myTable where ColumnX like '\%'`

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need

[image]