# PGAdmin / Postgres : Cannot write Timestamp data to Postgres (2018-04-18 05:40:28)

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

When I try to write the following date time format to Postgres using Pgadmin
2018-04-18 05:40:28

I get the following error. ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "2018-04-18 05:40:28"
CONTEXT:  COPY timestamp, line 1, column date: "2018-04-18 05:40:28"
I am trying to write the data using the timestamp format within Postgres.
Any pointers on where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Show us your `insert` statement

Comment: Here it is, thanks.  ALTER TABLE public."timestamp"
    ADD COLUMN date2 timestamp;

Comment: That's not the statement that generates the error (and it's not an insert statement to begin with)

Comment: I'm using the import facility in PGAdmin, " C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pgAdmin 4\\v3\\runtime\\psql.exe" --command " "\\copy public.\"timestamp\" (date) FROM 'C:/data/SEDEX2~1/TIMEST~1.TXT' CSV QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';"" Not sure if that's enough or perhaps I should try using an import statement instead of the import utility

Comment: @KeithC.: All defining information should go into the *question*. Please [edit] it. And have a look at this helpful site: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess: you have a leading **BOM (byte order mark)** in the file that should be removed.

- [How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%c3%af-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

Or some exotic **whitespace or non-printing character** that should be removed or replaced.

- [Trim trailing spaces with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699535/trim-trailing-spaces-with-postgresql/22701212#22701212)

And the offending character (well, the BOM is not a "character", strictly speaking, it's just mistaken for one) was not copied to the question. That would explain the otherwise contradicting error message.

To test, copy the `"2018-04-18 05:40:28"` part from the error message and paste it in a pgAdmin SQL editor window (which you seem to be using) and test:

```
SELECT '"﻿2018-04-18 05:40:28"' = '"2018-04-18 05:40:28"';
---------^  BOM here?
```

I added a leading BOM to demonstrate in the first string. Type the second string by hand to be sure it's plain ASCII. If you get `false`, we are on to something here.

But we cannot be too sure, your question is confusing and essential information is missing. Don't use the basic type names `timestamp` and `date` as identifiers, for sanity.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, I realized eventually that I had to change the timestamp format to match my data e.g. DMY to YMD. Easily done. Will add the additional info to my earlier question.