# How to use regexp_replace to replace all blank?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to use regexp_replace to replace all blank with '_'.

I use this statment:

> `select regexp_replace('"<div_class="CCL-temp-border"><div_class="input-group_moveDivEnd"_style="margin-bottom:_5px;_top:_auto;_left:_auto;_width:_100%;_position:_relative;_opacity:_1;_filter:_none;"_data-id="moveDivEnd_1545116285310">_;                          <span_class="input-group-addon_CCL-te (...)"', '\s', '_', 'g')`

But the result is this:

> `"<div_class="CCL-temp-border"><div_class="input-group_moveDivEnd"_style="margin-bottom:_5px;_top:_auto;_left:_auto;_width:_100%;_position:_relative;_opacity:_1;_filter:_none;"_data-id="moveDivEnd_1545116285310">_;_______<span_class="input-group-addon_CCL-t (...)"`

My statment is this:

> `select case when length(topiccontent)=0 THEN '_' else coalesce(regexp_replace(replace(replace(replace(topiccontent,chr(13), '_'),chr(10),'_'),' ','_'),'\s', '_', 'g'),'_') end  as topiccontent
>   from ccl_topics`

You can see the blank still exists, why?

[image]

Comment: Add you tried to use `( )` instead of `\s`?

Comment: @z3nth10n Yes,I tried,there is no effect!

Comment: It would help if you included the actual statements you have tried so far

Comment: @harmic I added all the attempts,please see my code.

Comment: Your first query seems to be working, see [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=770227c5c0b7b766974b33942413311f).Are you sure it's a space between `t` and `(` not any other unknown character?

Comment: I see it with notepad,it doesn't look like any other unknown character.

Comment: Did you verify your "blank" is a basic Latin space character (Unicode: U+0020 / ASCII 32) - or even member of  the character class `[[:space:]]` (shorthand `\s`)? The character I see in your question is, but the original may have been lost in translation. Whitespace can be tricky. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22701212/939860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why it can't be replaced.

There are some character restrictions when the data is pasted out from database.

The omitted part is converted to `(...)`.

So `(...)` is not real characters, but ellipses.

For example, more than 600 characters exist in a column of a table, and then paste  it,the result with ellipsis marks.