How to find rows with non-printable characters in my table?
I have a database table which has some values with non-printable character, my question is how to find the rows having those characters. Is there any way to create the select query on some columns and use a regex to find the rows?
I've tried something like CHECK (my_column ~ '^[\x00-\x7F]*$'), but in my case I don't want to add a constraint, I want to find the rows.

this might help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167566/querying-non-ascii-rows-from-postgres

maybe adapt this from sql-server to postgresql https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/function-to-find-non-printable-characters

Since non-printable chrs means ascii (0-31,127), Maybe a combination of https://catonmat.net/my-favorite-regex   and  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

That CHECK constraint doesn't look good. It will allow char #0, that is non-printable. Now a Tab (char #9) is printable, right? What about new-line (char #10) or carriage-return (char #13)? Form-feed/New-page (char #12) probably falls in the same category; the Vertical-Tab (char #11) is probably non-printable... or is it? What about the "Terminal bell/beep" (char #8)? Probably not.

@Bibou simplefy you question with some example ...

Is "non-printable characters" the right term? In other words: what exactly do you want to find? UNICODE has made this rather sophisticated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22701212/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63311776/939860

@Bibou What means non-printable characters, every unicode should be convertible...

@ArtBindu I mean not visible characters like : u200b (zero width space)

Please add some examples of columns data including non-printable character @Bibou. I Will add Regex Validation for that...

@ArtBindu, let's say we have a table with the following columns : First_name, last_name, adress, ... etc, and I have some names having some non-printable characters, they are not visibles, but they will cause some issues on Java code. if you use some editors, you can see them, example : ArtBindu\u200b.
Since I have many tenants on Prod, I wan to execute a SQL query to see the tenants having this issue.

Unicode characters are specified as follows:
1. \XXXX (4 hexadecimal digits)
2. \+XXXXXX (6 hexadecimal digits) 
3. \uXXXX (4 hexadecimal digits) 
4. \UXXXXXXXX (8 hexadecimal digits)

According to your discussion your format is \uXXXX.
Now, postgresql already have string function for Unicode conversion
unistr ( text )

This is an example of postgresql table which contains few Unicode data:
CREATE TABLE T (id int, data varchar(255));
INSERT INTO T VALUES
  (1, 'C' || U&'\00F4' || E'te d\'Ivoire'),
  (2, 'C\u00F4te d\u0027Ivoire'),
  (3, 'ArtBindu\u0075\u002e\u002e\u002e'),
  (4, '\u0126ello Worl\u014A');

So, I have added solution for Trim Unicode value and convert Unicode value to text. You may use anyone of them according to your requirements and query as follows:
select id,
  data,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(data, '\\u[0-9A-F]{4}', '', 1, 0, 'i') as trim_unicode,
  unistr(data) as convert_unicode_to_str
from T;

output: 

Testing query: db<>fiddle
Here, I used postgresql Pattern Matching function REGEXP_REPLACE describe as follows:

