# Search for string that start or finish with spaces and removing these spaces

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that some column have spaces, like this:

```
Column A
-----------
"text 1"
" text 2"
"text 3 "
" text 4 "
```

I want to do a **select** that return those columns with spaces (beginning or end)

```
" text 2"
"text 3 "
" text 4 "
```

Is that possible?

After search for them, How could I update those columns to remove the spaces?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a regular expression: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: `UPDATE table set "Column A" = btrim("Column A");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with REGEX:

```
select column_a
  from your_table
 where column_a ~* '(^\s+)*(\s+$)';
```

The problem with `trim` is that it removes only spaces with unicode U+0020. TABS and others will not be caught.

And to update the column:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET col_a = substring(col_a, '\S(?:.*\S)*')
 WHERE col_a in (
    select col_a from mytable
     where col_a ~* '^\s+|\s+$'
);
```

Comment: regex is expensive. use comment from bruno caballo.

Comment: @fukanchik I agree with you. But `trim` does not work the way I want, the explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22701212/9033414 If not using `trim` the other way would be `substring`.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `btrim()`:

```
select column_a
  from your_table
 where btrim(column_a) != column_a;
```