# Splitting a string by a regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, split

I have a string with words that sometimes have after them `,`, `;`, `.`, `:`. It is possible to have one or more spaces after these punctuation characters. I need to extract just the existent words.

For example, from:

```
'I use Python, SQL, C++. I need: apples and oranges'
```

I need to get:

```
I, use, Python, SQL, C++, I, need, apples, and, oranges
```

The `split_part` function can be used to split on a character. Is there a way to use this function (or a similar one) to get this splitting. I am thinking on a regular expression instead o the character but I am not sure which one to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a regex can easily do this :)

```
# SELECT regexp_split_to_table(
    'I use Python, SQL, C++. I need: apples and oranges',
    '[ .,:;]+');
┌───────────────────────┐
│ regexp_split_to_table │
├───────────────────────┤
│ I                     │
│ use                   │
│ Python                │
│ SQL                   │
│ C++                   │
│ I                     │
│ need                  │
│ apples                │
│ and                   │
│ oranges               │
└───────────────────────┘
(10 rows)
```

Comment: I'd recommend `'[,;.:]? +'` or `'[,;.:]?\s+'` as pattern to respect multiple spaces or white spaces in general.

Comment: @stickybit - why do you say that about respecting white space?

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW: Why not? It's more flexible, if one wants that.

Comment: @stickybit - I'd only go for that if I were **specifically** asked - still, it's a nice little one to remember *au cas où*. Regular expressions aren't my strongest suit - though I have been looking at them recently! As I said elsewhere, a Swiss-Army knife for strings, but abstruse, complex and obscure which, along with subtle differences in different environments' implementations, make them a propeller-head's wet-dream!

Answer (score 1):

#### `ts_parse()`

You could use [`ts_parse()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-DEBUG-TABLE) with the 'default' [text search parser](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-parsers.html):

```sql
test=> SELECT token
test-> FROM   ts_parse ('default', 'I use Python, SQL, C++. I need: apples and oranges')
test-> WHERE  tokid <> 12;
  token  
---------
 I
 use
 Python
 SQL
 C
 I
 need
 apples
 and
 oranges
(10 rows)
```

Unfortunately, the `+` sign is also trimmed, being categorized as "blank" or "Space symbols" (`tokid = 12`). That's how the `'default'` text search parser operates. You could write your own, but it's not trivial, must be done in the C language and as superuser.

Apart from the `+`, it would be perfect, and **much faster** than regexp processing.

To see a complete list of token types known to the default parser:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_token_type('default');
```

To get a detailed debug view:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ts_debug('I use Python, SQL, C++. I need: apples and oranges foo@sdf.at 234 0699/19477759 -132 -34.547')
```

#### Regular expression

While sticking to regular expressions, you can use `regexp_split_to_table()` like Wolph suggested. I'd suggest this pattern for your request:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('...', '[\s,;.:]+');
```

Takes any string consisting only of whitespace characters and your listed punctuation marks as delimiter.

[`\s` is a class shorthand for `[[:space:]]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) (whitespace characters) and can be included in a character class like demonstrated. Equivalent: `'[[:space:],;.:]+'`. It covers *most* non-printing characters. But UNICODE sucks in this regard, and there are always more of them. See:

- [Trim trailing spaces with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699535/trim-trailing-spaces-with-postgresql/22701212#22701212)