# Removing a list of keywords from string

Tags: postgresql

I have a data column that contains a blob of text. For example, 'John Doe lives in Emerald Street'. I would like to remove a list of texts from the string. I have some list like this (lives, in, street). I would like to select a new data column converting the text to 'John Doe Emerald'.

Comment: You have to be a lot more specific. Define word delimiters exactly. How to deal with white space? Can words contain delimiter characters? Postgres version? Max / min / avg number of words in text and list. The sequence of replacements can matter ... How many rows in the table? Ideally, a basic table definition, some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

First you can create an `AGGREGATE` function based on the `replace` function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace(x text, y text, old_txt text, new_txt text)
RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
    SELECT replace(COALESCE(x,y), old_txt, new_txt)
$$ ;

DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS replace_agg (text, text, text) CASCADE ;
CREATE AGGREGATE replace_agg (text, text, text)
(
  sfunc = replace
, stype = text
);
```

Then you can iterate on the `replace_agg` function within a SELECT statement :

```
SELECT replace_agg (your_table.your_column, k.keyword, '')
FROM (SELECT 'John Doe lives in Emerald Street' as your_column) as your_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT unnest(array['lives', 'in', 'Street']) as keyword) as k
```

with the following result :

```
'John Doe   Emerald'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the simple case:

- Words are delimited by a single space character - in the table and in the replacement string.
- No punctuation like in natural language. No leading or trailing noise.
- Case sensitive matching.
- Remove *all* matches (as opposed to just the first).

And a table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE strings(id serial PRIMARY KEY, string text);

INSERT INTO strings(string) VALUES
  ('John Doe lives in Emerald Street')
, ('John Doe lives in Emerald Street as john DOE');
```

#### [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)

A short solution:

```
SELECT *, rtrim(regexp_replace(string, '(John|Doe|Emerald) ?', '', 'g')) FROM strings;
```

`|` separates alternative *branches* in a regular expression.

Related:

- [Trim trailing spaces with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699535/trim-trailing-spaces-with-postgresql/22701212#22701212)

Or, with your original replacement string as input:

```
SELECT *, rtrim(regexp_replace(string, '(' || replace('John Doe Emerald', ' ', '|') || ') ?', '', 'g')) FROM strings;
```

#### Set operations

Regular expressions are typically expensive. This may be faster (minimal form):

```sql
SELECT s.id, string_agg(word, ' ') AS string2
FROM   strings s, unnest(string_to_array(s.string, ' ')) word
WHERE  word <> ALL (string_to_array('John Doe Emerald', ' '))
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

To avoid any ambiguity and make sure to preserve original order:

```sql
SELECT s.id, string_agg(word, ' ' ORDER BY ord) AS string2
FROM   strings s, unnest(string_to_array(s.string, ' ')) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(word, ord)
WHERE  t.word <> ALL (string_to_array('John Doe Emerald', ' '))
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Which is typically faster with `ORDER BY` in a separate subquery:

```sql
SELECT sub.id, string_agg(sub.word, ' ') AS string2
FROM  (
   SELECT s.id, t.word
   FROM   strings s, unnest(string_to_array(s.string, ' ')) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(word, ord)
   WHERE  t.word <> ALL (string_to_array('John Doe Emerald', ' '))
   ORDER  BY s.id, t.ord
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Often simpler to integrate with `LATERAL` subquery:

```sql
SELECT s.id, sub.string2
FROM   strings s
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(t.word, ' ' ORDER BY t.ord) AS string2
   FROM   unnest(string_to_array(s.string, ' ')) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(word, ord)
   WHERE  t.word <> ALL (string_to_array('John Doe Emerald', ' '))   
   ) sub
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This way, we need not `GROUP BY` in the outer `SELECT`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e72f09ad3fdd7d95e083a0cc2f911ee7)*