# Replacing empty and null strings in Redshift with default strings when querying?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

My table has some null and empty strings, these look ugly when I query the table so I want to replace them with other values. I don't own the data so I can't modify the table itself, this needs to happen when I query.

I tried using `regexp_replace` to replace the empty strings with `regexp_replace(column, '^$', '(no value found/some other custom message)'` which didn't work

Comment: Are you sure they're empty strings and not blanks (that is, all whitespace)?

Comment: If the column is null, use coalesce().

Answer (score 1):

Convert null to blank using [`coalesce()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html) before applying your regexp_replace:

```
regexp_replace(coalesce(thing, ''), '^\s*$', 'default')
```

---

With Redshift you can also use `nvl()` instead of `coalesce()` for a briefer solution, but `coalesce()` is the SQL standard and therefore arguably more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest way to replace null *and* empty strings:

```
CASE WHEN column <> '' THEN column ELSE 'default' END
```

Only applicable to string types. Most other data types have no "empty" value.

This uses only a very basic [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) expression, so it works in any RDBMS (certainly including Postgres and Redshift) that handles null values according to the SQL standard.

Another standard SQL way:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(column, ''), 'default')
```

See:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

Regular expressions are way to expensive for the simple task (IMO).

If you have to deal with non-printing characters, you need to do more. See:

- [Trim trailing spaces with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699535/trim-trailing-spaces-with-postgresql/22701212#22701212)

Comment: man your answers are always the best! Anytime I see your name I rejoice.

Answer (score 0):

`null` and empty string have to be treated separately. In addition, there's a difference between `''` (empty) and `'      '` (blank).

`null` is "unknown". `regexp_replace(null, '^$', 'default')` doesn't do anything because the value it's matching is unknown. The match fails and it returns `null`.

Instead, use [`coalesce`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html). It returns the first non-null value. `coalesce(thing, 'default')`.

To capture empty and blank strings, search for `^\s*$`. `regexp_replace(thing, '^\s*$', 'default')`.

We put them together like so...

```
select
  coalesce(regexp_replace(thing, '^\s*$', 'default'), 'default')
from test;
```

If `thing` is `null`, `regexp_replace` will return `null`, and `coalesce` will return `'default'`.

If `thing` is empty or blank, `regexp_replace` will return `default` and `coalesce` will return `default`.

If `thing` is none of those, `regexp_replace` will return `thing` and `coalesce` will return `thing`.

An alternative that might be easier to understand is:

```
select
  case 
    when trim(word) = '' then 'default'
    else coalesce(word, 'default')
  end
from test
```

If you like, you can [put this into a function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html). We can declare it `immutable` (the same arguments always produce the same result) potentially giving it a performance boost.

```
create function replace_blanks(text, text) returns text
immutable
as $$
  select coalesce(regexp_replace($1, '^\s*$', $2), $2)
$$ language sql;

select replace_blanks(word, 'default') from test;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/EqvhG0N5) in PostgreSQL. Redshift is derived from PostgreSQL so it should work the same.