# SQL select rows containing substring in text field

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have CLIENTS_WORDS table with columns: ID, CLIENT_ID, WORD in Postgresql database

```
ID|CLIENT_ID|WORD
1 |1242     |word1
2 |1242     |WordX.foo
3 |1372     |nextword
4 |1999     |word1
```

In this table possible about 100k-500k rows.
I have query string like this:

```
'Some people tell word1 to someone'
'Another stringWordX.foo too possible'
```

I wish select * from table where WORD column text contains in query string.
Now I use select

```
select * from CLIENTS_WORDS
where strpos('Some people tell word1 to someone', WORD) > 0
```

My question, where is the best perfomance/fast way to retrieve matched rows?

Comment: Does lower case / upper case matter? What is your version of Postgres?

Comment: ignore upper/lower case, postgres 9.3 latest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get better performance with [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and JOIN. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.client_id
FROM   unnest(string_to_array('Some people tell word1 ...', ' ')) AS t(word)
JOIN   clients_words c USING (word);
```

Details of the query depend on missing details of your requirements. This is splitting the string at *space* characters.

A **more flexible** tool would be [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), where you can use [character classes or shorthands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) for your delimiter characters. Like:

```
regexp_split_to_table('Some people tell word1 to someone', '\s') AS t(word)
regexp_split_to_table('Some people tell word1 to someone', '\W') AS t(word)
```

- Related answer: [Django. PostgreSQL. regexp_split_to_table not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907041/django-postgresql-regexp-split-to-table-not-working/8908163#8908163)
- [A search for more answers for regular expression class shorthands.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D%20regular%20expression%20class%20shorthand)

Of course the column `clients_words.word` needs to be indexed for performance:

```
CREATE INDEX clients_words_word_idx ON clients_words (word)
```

Would be very fast.

#### Ignore word boundaries

If you want to ignore word boundaries altogether, the whole matter becomes much more expensive. `LIKE` / `ILIKE` in combination with a trigram GIN index would come to mind. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

However, your case is **backwards** and the index is not going to help. You'll have to inspect every single row for a partial match - making queries *very* expensive. The superior approach is to *reverse* the operation: split words and *then* search.

Comment: Its works if searchable word can be split by ' ' space but if try 'Another stringWordX.foo too possible' will not match WordX.foo

Comment: @Dmitry: I added a bit more about regular expressions and pattern matching.